# How to test the impact of several variables on the order rate of a given product?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

A retail business in the beauty & cosmetics segment sells it's products using a magazine. The magazine contains products and prices, along with pictures and product descriptions.

The salesman shows the magazine to the customer, which picks the products and order products directly with the salesman.

The company can make changes to several variables, which presumably will impact the order rate of the products. For example:

- If I show this product on the front page of the magazine, what's the impact on it's order rate?
- If I show a picture of some model woman using this lipstick instead of showing just the lipstick, what's the impact on it's order rate?
- And many others variables such as the above ones.

The company wants to test the impact that each of these variables have on the order rate of a given product. How to do that?

Comment: Have you heard of AB testing?  This would be a good use case for AB testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term you will want to search for is "AB Testing".  In short, AB testing creates two variants of your magazine (version A and B, hence the name) and *randomly* distributes them to salesmen and customers to be used as you've described.  The *random* part is incredibly important.  Without getting into too much detail, the randomness allows us to conclude that any$^1$ differences we observe are due to the change we made in the magazine and not due to some other factor we failed to account for.

So the procedure would look like the following:

- We first determine what we want to accomplish (increase order rate) and how we want to try doing that (e.g. change the copy to show just the lipstick rather than a woman using the lipstick).
- We settle on a smallest change we would find interesting.  A change in order rate of 1% may or may not be interesting or "worth it" to the company.  That is for you and the stakeholders to decide.  Once the smallest interesting change is decided upon, we compute how many samples we would need in order to detect this change.
- We settle on a way to measure order rate.  I presume you mean number of orders made divided by the number of interactions with the sales people.
- Create the magazines, send them out, record the order rate for the two groups, and use statistics to determine if the difference we observed between the two groups is larger than we would expect under the assumptions we make about the data + the test we are using.

Now, this is not a bullet proof set of instructions.  Namely, if sales people see more than one customer (I presume they do) then the results will depend largely on who sees who.  If the change in copy happens to have no change in order rate, but we happen by chance to send version B to a handful of extremely productive sales reps, this could bias the data unfavourably.

Various complications to this outline I have made exist.  I'm hesitant to give "if then" sort of rules for people to follow, because in my experience people always find a way to complicate the analysis.  I would highly recommend that a person familiar with statistics$^2$ help design whatever it is you intend to do.

---

Footnotes

1. Not *any* change, I'm being a imprecise in order to be useful.
2. And by "familiar", I do not mean "Yea, I took a course in stats 4 years ago and remember doing t tests". Someone who is more familiar with the pitfalls of such an analysis.

Comment: thanks. Is it possible to test the effect of more than 1 variable at once?

Comment: @marcus Possibly.  You can use regression to analyze the outcomes in that case.